# facebook apps padding error

Tags: python, facebook, padding

i have created on apps on facebook but i am facing padding problem.
the problem is as follows.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1306, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1294, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1062, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1060, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1047, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/app/exampleapp.py", line 167, in index
    access_token = get_token()
  File "/app/exampleapp.py", line 134, in get_token
    data = json.loads(urlsafe_b64decode(str(encoded_data[1])))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 112, in urlsafe_b64decode
    """
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 76, in b64decode

TypeError: Incorrect padding
```

can anybody help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use pdb to tell us what's encoded_data[1] in exampleapp.py line 134?

It's just something bad about the base64 encoding, probably some whitespace that has to be stripped off using .strip() (I'd try that). But without seeing its value it's hard to guess.
(Sorry, this is a comment and not an answer, but I can't comment yet).

Comment: thanks to reply but i am not getting what you actually say to do.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the value of encoded_data[1] in exampleapp.py line 134? Maybe simply print it out and post it here. Without seeing it, it's difficult to say what the problem with its base64 encoding is. You can also try to use encoded_data[1].strip() in that line, maybe it will solve it.